# Automatically Find/Replace fixed set of phrases in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, find-and-replace, grammar

I want to perform the following Find/Replace operations (or equivalent) in Word:

For example:

```
End of sentence:  also `.`, `?`, `!`
1. `. ` by `.` (xInf)
2. `.` by `.  `
3. ` .` by `.` (xInf)
```

**Edit**: `xInf` above means repeat the Find/Replace operation until there are no instances left in the document

(Full list [here](https://pastebin.com/8crnNdsi), meant for cleaning a manuscript - it's not perfect!  Suggestions welcome)

Is there a simple way to do this using a Macro instead of manually doing each of the above steps using the regular Find/Replace dialog?  (I have zero VBA skills...)

Comment: What is `(xinf)` ?

Comment: Sorry,  that meant repeat the operation until there are zero instances

Answer (score 1):

You may record a macro once in order to have it available for repeated usage in one
document or in all documents (by storing in `Normal.dotm`). No knowledge of VBA
is necessary.

See this Microsoft article for full details:
[Create or run a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c).

Note that in order to store the macro in a document, the document must have the
postfix of `.docm` instead of `.docx`.

Comment: I don't think I can record a static macro, as I need to repeat some Find/Replace operations in a `while(there is at least one instance)` loop.

Comment: In that case you can take the recorded macro, which will be in VBA format, and improve it to do what you want. But you will need to know VBA a bit for that.